# Thymeleaf th:each repair

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to use the th:each function for my site, to find all the dogs in my database, and am using the following code. In my controller, I have:

```
@Controller
public class DogController {

private DogDatabase database = new DogDatabase();
@RequestMapping(value = "/allDogs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllDogs(Model model)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = database.getAllIDs();
    System.out.println(ids.size());
    Dog[] dogs = new Dog[ids.size()+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i)
    {
        dogs[i] = database.getDog(ids.get(i));
    }
    model.addAttribute("dogs", dogs);

    return "getAllDogs";
}
```

After this for loop, I did a println on each object in the array and verified, that all my dog objects are valid and not null. After verifying that the array is correct, I am passing it as a model and trying to get it in the html. The current problem is that when I go to the html, it displays nothing. I'm not getting any thymeleaf errors, just a blank screen. Attached is my html code where I call th:each

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>All Dogs</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <th:block th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td th:text="${dog.name}">Name</td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit One and Two: edit was to fix errors, that was not in my code

Edit Three: I tried switching dog and dogs in the iterator (as in code above,) but now I am getting an error that there was an "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "dog.name" (template: "getAllDogs" - line 13, col 21)"

This does not make sense, however, as I use dog.name throughout the site, and getName() is public in Dog class. Upon request, I am adding my dog class: https://pastebin.com/Lknc8dtZ

Comment: Your namespace is wrong. It should read `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`.

Comment: Is that comma after dog in the th:each a typo?

Comment: @Catweazle it was

Comment: I added the namespace of xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org, and it did not resolve. @M.Deinum

Comment: Try adding "return this.name" in the getName() method !

Comment: But the class looks alright, can't find anything wrong :/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is here:

```
<th:block th:each="dogs : ${dog}">
```

sience in your controller you are binding the Dog[] array to the variable "dogs":

```
model.addAttribute("dogs", dogs);
```

So in your template you should iterate like this:

```
<th:block th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td th:text="${dog.name}">Name</td>
            </tr>
</th:block>
```

to look for each dog in the dogs array :)

Comment: When I try that, I get "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "dog.name" (template: "getAllDogs" - line 13, col 21)," but I know that dog.name is appropriate, as I use it in other html files, and I do have a name field in my Dog.java class with a matching getName()

Comment: That's weird ... I'm a newbie too, sorry I can't help you much :( The iteration was wrong thought, you should do it as I've posted. Maybe you can share you Dog class ?

Comment: @AndreEllis is your `getName()` public in Dog.java?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza and Nacho, I added them above

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre I'm guessing it's because your array has a null object.  you're making it one bigger than `ids.size()` and so on the last iteration of the `th:each`, you are calling `getName()` on a null object.

Comment: It's not me who was asking @Metroids, but thanks for the info, hope the poster reads this, might be the answer for his problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason here to use an `array` of `Dog[]` rather than a `List<Dog>` -- and that is probably what is causing your error.  You are creating an `array` that is too big, and so it's trying to call `getName()` on a null `object`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/allDogs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllDogs(Map<String, Object> model) {
    List<Dog> dogs = database.getAllIDs()
            .stream()
            .map(id -> database.getDog(id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    model.put("dogs", dogs);
    return "getAllDogs";
}
```

Also, you have don't need the extra `<th:block />`.   You can move the `th:each` directly onto the `<tr>`.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td th:text="${dog.name}">Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```